# append a string to the params name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, append, parameters

In my rails app I am stuck with a situation where I need to add a string to the params name,

i.e, I have a params array `params[:attended]`, but I need to have this as `params[:attended_61]` and `_61` must be appended. 61 is the ID of an active record row object. I have that value in `@sys.id`. Then please tell me how I can convert `params[:attended]` to `params[:attended_61]`. Thank you.

Comment: Better to give the final use case, there must be conventional and simple solution than this kind of hacking.

Comment: I have tried a lot to get it on the conventional way. But, couldn't. that's y I ought to have the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Billy Chan is right, what you're trying to do sounds very strange and you should probably rethink your whole approach.

But if you must do such an odd thing, you could just do this:

```
params[:"attended_#{@sys.id}"] = params.delete(:attended)
```

Or, since `params` will be a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, you could skip the symbolification:

```
params["attended_#{@sys.id}"] = params.delete(:attended)
# or even
params["attended_#{@sys.id}"] = params.delete('attended')
```

`params` is simply a method that returns a Hash, you can change that Hash as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as given below.

```
params["attended_#{@sys.id}"]
```

Perfectly working !!

Answer (score 0):

also you can add **:** to the params name to be like the natural **params[:var]** name and it will work well also to be like that

```
params[:"attended_#{@sys.id}"]
```